# Filling the second column of a 2d array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I filled the first column with random numbers in the range of [20,25], now I want the user to fill the second column with random numbers in the range of [20,25]. How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int Temperature[5][2] = {{20},{21},{22},{23},{24}};

    printf("I created a 2D array of size 5x2,");
    printf("and I filled the first column with random values in the range [20,25]\n");

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",Temperature[i][0]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Please fill the second column with values in the range [0,20]\n");

    int i, j;
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("Value[%d]:",j);
        scanf("%d", &Temperature[0][j]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try this: `scanf("%d", &Temperature[j][1]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a little bit assuming that you expect the user input numbers between 20 and 25, and added some logs in order to help your understanding.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, Temperature[5][2] = {{20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}};

  printf("I created a 2D array of size 5x2,");
  printf("and I filled the first column with random values in the range [20,25] (inclusive)\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", Temperature[i][0]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\nPlease fill the second column with values in the range [20,25] (inclusive)\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    do
    {
      printf("Value[%d]:", i);
      scanf("%d", &Temperature[i][1]);
    } while (Temperature[i][1] < 20 || Temperature[i][1] > 25);
  }

  printf("and the user filled the second column with values in the range [20,25] (inclusive)\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    printf("%d \n", Temperature[i][1]);
  }
}
```

Note that values are not random, first column consists of the values I initialized and the second column consists of the values user entered.

Comment: thank you so much, i should add an if statement in the loop to make sure the user entered values between 20 and 25 right? and how can i print that array ?

Comment: I printed that array at the end of execution. You can run and see it. And yes, if you want the user input to be between some specific values, you should check user input. I did that in another loop ( `do - while` ) to force to the user to input valid values until my expectation is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

For a two dimensional array in C, 
array[x][y] ---> denotes x<sup>th</sup> row and y<sup>th</sup> column

Since arrays are 0-indexed, 2nd column in your example implies column number should be 1 (0 is the first column)

Modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int Temperature[5][2]={{20},{21},{22},{23},{24}};
    printf("I created a 2D array of size 5x2,");
    printf("and I filled the first column with random values in the range [20,25]\n");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        //correction done here
        printf("%d ",Temperature[i][0]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Please fill the second column with values in the range [0,20]\n");
    int i, j;
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("Value[%d]:",j);
        scanf("%d", &Temperature[j][1]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, can you help me in printing the array

Comment: printf("Two Dimensional array elements:\n");
   for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
      for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
         printf("%d\n ", Temperature[i][j]);
         
      }
   }

Comment: x -> row
y -> column

Comment: this is what i did but it prints each element alone not as 2 columns and five rows

Comment: for(i=0; i<5; { 
  printf("%d %d\n", Temperature[i][0], Temperature[i][1]);
 }
This is one of the way

Comment: i think you could do that in an easier way but im not sure

Comment: This is correcting the idea you suggested:

for(i=0; i<5; i++) 
 { 
  for(j=0;j<2;j++) 
   { 
    printf("%d ", Temperature[i][j]);
   }
  printf("\n");
 }

Comment: This code produces an 5x2 2d array, but question asks for 2x5 structured one if I get the question correct. @Milan I downvoted, because the answer you provide produces a different structured 2d array that the question asker asked for.

Comment: @keskinsaf I followed the print statement in the asker's first printf statement:
printf("I created a 2D array of size 5x2,");
Also the asker has declared the array of size 5x2

Comment: @Milan you are absolutely right, there is an inconsistency between the question text and code block logs.

Comment: There is not an inconsistency, I misunderstood the question. Sorry @Milan

Comment: No problem @keskinsaf, you can remove the earlier downvote.

Comment: @Milan I can't, because there is no new update for your answer yet. So, I edited and waiting for approval. I will upvote when edit is accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213495/discussion-between-milan-and-keskinsaf).

Answer (score 1):

```c
&Temperature[0][j]
```

The actual element would be under `Temperature[j][1]`.

Comment: thank you, plus do you know how can i print the array as 2 columns after that?

Comment: printf("Two Dimensional array elements:\n");
   for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
      for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
         printf("%d\n ", Temperature[i][j]);
         
      }
   }

Comment: this is what i did

Comment: `for(i=0; i<5; i++) printf("%d %d\n", Temperature[i][0], Temperature[i][1]);`